# Azure AD Claims mapping requires custom signing key

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We're using application client credentials to authenticate via Azure AD.

When we do this the `Identity.Name` is `null`. This is because there is no name claim mapped into the JWT.

We discovered you can map custom claims, like so: [Claims mapping in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping#claims-mapping-policy-type).

When you apply the policy to the application, the next time you authenticate you receive an error:

> "AADSTS50146: This application is required to be configured with an application-specific signing key."

Cool, there is a way out of this though: [New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential?view=azureadps-2.0).  It indicates you can create a Symmetric signing key in your application and voila -- we now have a JWT with the custom claim.

The problem, not resolved: it generates a jwt with a HS256 header, not the required RS256 algorithm.

When I try to authorize the jwt against the application. It fails, unauthorized.

Now I am stuck, I can map a custom claim, but with no way to authorize the jwt :(

I there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our application was using:

```
UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
```

Changing the application to:

```
UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
```

Allows us to authorize the JWT token. considering the claims mapping feature is in preview; I'll take this as an answer for now. Assuming when the feature is released we can add Asymmetric application signing keys.

For now I am happy to just map the appid claim (and does not require a custom claim mapping) to the name claim, like so :

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Add("appid", System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name);
```

Answer (score 24):

It's good to remember to set acceptMappedClaims to true in the application registration manifest in Azure.

Comment: Please make sure both the values mentioned below are properly set in the manifest file:    "acceptMappedClaims": true,
 "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,

Comment: According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute), accessTokenAcceptedVersion should be set to 2 if using AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount

Comment: Warning
Do not set the acceptMappedClaims property to true for multi-tenant apps, which can allow malicious actors to create claims-mapping policies for your app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/entra/identity-platform/jwt-claims-customization?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_IAM#update-the-application-manifest

Comment: Curious if anyone knows, is this property only configurable in the manifest? Or is there another section in the UI where you can change this property? It just seems odd to me that I could not find documentation on this requirement

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7566) the error message can also be because the policy is invalid. In my case, I was able to get the error to stop by using the `Set-AzureADPolicy` PowerShell command to change the policy and the error went away. I believe I had some invalid claim IDs.

Answer (score 1):

In my case somehow helped to switch ***Manifest*** property ***`acceptMappedClaims`*** to ***`true`***.
Previously there was `null` value. I downloaded `Manifest`, changed mentioned value to `true` and uploaded it back to Azure AD.
I also generated one `secret` in ***`Certificates and secrets`***
Then I logged-out and logged-in in my application and I had custom claim accessible.

[image: Change manifest]

[image: Create secret]